# how to get sum and count from this result set?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Mysql query returns result like this

```
collector amount    name
1     0.00      gihan
1     2000.00   gihan
1     2500.00   gihan
1     11502.00  gihan
2     1140.00   lasita
```

i want to get array of result like

```
collector  amount  count  name
1         16002.00   4    gihan
2          1140.00   1    lasita
```

any idea how to loop result set to get sum for matching collector and same time get count and put result into a new array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to solve this in PHP, when you can have MySQL do the work for you?

```sql
SELECT collector, sum(amount) as amount, count(*) as `count`, name 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY collector, name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT collector,sum(amount) as amount,COUNT(*) as count,name
FROM Table
GROUP BY  collector,name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SUM and COUNT to get a direct result. No loops necessary.

```
SELECT Collector,SUM(Amount) as Amount,COUNT(Amount) as Count,Name
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Collector,Name
```